# Недоступность сайта

Tags: домен, dns

Всем привет, уже который месяц сайт то открывается то не открывается, уже надоело, если мой сайт не доступен и показывает в браузере:

> К сожалению google chrome не может
> открыть страницу

То что делать ?  обратился к хостеру там мне сказали обратитесь к регистратору домена, и соответственно регистратор меня отправил к хостеру, надоело, в чем может быть проблема ?  сайт:  [Freelife](http://freelife.tj)
Иногда бывает так, что у меня с компьютера не открывает а у друзей открывает, в чем может быть проблема ?

Comment: Я не спец, пробуй по имени домена и по ip заходить... если по ip не заходит, тогда обращайся к хостеру...
заюзай команду ping...

Comment: @Максуд, Это вопрос на форум [БитКод](http://user.hashcode.ru/).

Comment: Вбил, показывает все нормально

Answer (score 1):

1е что могу посоветовать (что уже впринципе советовали) это сделать пинг на сайт:

в командной строке:

`ping freelife.tj`

У меня выдаёт:

Обмен пакетами с freelife.tj **[178.63.95.130]** по 32 байт:

....

Обратите внимание на ip адрес, если команда ping не может определить ip адрес то в этом виновен dns регистратор, в прочем проблема может быть и в вашем провайдере, попросите друзей (желательно что бы у них были отличные от вашего провайдеры) выполнить туже команду (ping)

Если же ip адрес определило правильно, но обмен пакетами не происходит - то тут уже виноват хостер (опять же может быть виноват ваш провайдер, попросите друзей выполнить команду).

Comment: спасибо за полезный и нужный инфо.  Я только что передал ссылку своим друзьям, у всех заходит, захожу сам заходит, но спустя пять минут сам зашел не открывается сайт, а у друзей открывает, даже у тех у кого сайт и домен зареган у одного провайдера! Друг вбил ping и показывает тоже самое что и у меня, а точнее тоже что и у Вас. Есть еще какие то варианты решения проблемы ?  и можете подсказать точно, к кому мне предъявить претензию ?  к хостеру или к регистратору домена ?

Comment: Если у вас не заходит, а у друзей заходит, то скорее всего претензии предъявлять нужно вашему провайдеру.

Comment: понятно.. завтра я пойду к своему провайдеру и предъявлю эту проблему, и отпишусь в этой теме завтра.

Comment: пинговать лучше длительное время. ``ping site.ru -t`` если временные сбои, то их за 4 пинга можно и не увидеть.